# Excluding files from web logs

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

Looking through my web logs, I see a lot of entries that don't interest me. Some of them are commonly used images, css files, and scripts, which I can easily exclude by un-checking the 'log visits' check box in IIS for the folder properties.

I would also like to exclude log entries for certain common requests which are not in their own folders. Mostly, 'favicon.ico'. 'scriptresource.axd', and 'webresource.axd'. These (especially scriptresource.axd) make up almost a third of a typical log file on my site.

So, the question is, how do I tell IIS not to log these requests? And is there any reason that this is a bad idea?

Comment: How is this programming related? http://serverfault.com is more suitable to server administration and configuration questions.

Comment: What are you using to parse logs? You can selectively ignore items using Microsoft's log parser http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en

Comment: @darin - I suppose serverfault make more sense, but I am so used to SO that I didn't think of it. Plus, the solution may require some code...

Comment: @Ray, don't worry, server admins know how to write code :-)

Comment: @iivel - I am not concerned with parsing - I know I can skip items. I am more interested in keeping the file size down for backups, and for when I look at them manually for troubleshooting. Also, for curiosity

Comment: @darin - I hope so - I am the programmer *and* the server admin!

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this, would be to create an another webpage in IIS with a subdomain with loging turned off and move those files to that webpage. Well you will have to update all links to point to that subdomain.

www.domain.com - html

file.domain.com - files (favicon.ico, ...)